# How to test approximate values in Fitnesse

Tags: c#, integration-testing, fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm using Fitnesse with FitSharp to run integration tests. I'm using the RowFixture to test a table of numerical results and need to be able to test an approximate value to about 3 decimal places. How can I achieve this? I read somewhere about using ~= but this does not appear to work on tables

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Slim Test System in FitNesse offers an [approximately equals](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ValueComparisons) operator (`~=`) as you point out but I agree that it is *not* available in fitSharp. Two possibilities to consider:

First (though I have not had occasion to use them) fitSharp offers a variety of [cell operators](http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/CellOperators.html)--see, in particular, *Compare Foating Point* on that list.

Second, one technique I have used is this:
[image: Example of specifying precision]

That is, my Math fixture lets you specify a precision (defaulting to two places if unspecified). The code-behind for that is quite simple:

```
    private double DoCalculation()
    {
        . . .
        return Math.Round(_result, Precision);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the ~= operator do what you need?  It's pretty easy to add to fitSharp.