# How use optional cell operators in fitsharp

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

FitSharp supports optional cell Operators

How do I use this one specifically?
http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/CompareFloatingPoint.html

I have read the bottom of this page
http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/CellOperators.html

I have tried putting the `Processor.AddOperator("fitSharp.Fit.Operators.CompareFloatingPoint");` in my method under test.

```
public class Division
{
    public double Numerator { get; set; }
    public double Denominator { get; set; }

    public double Quotient()
    {
        Processor.AddOperator("fitSharp.Fit.Operators.CompareFloatingPoint");
        return Numerator / Denominator;
    }
}
```

I have tried a suiteconfig file

```
<suiteConfig>
    <Fit.Operators>
        <Add>fitSharp.Fit.Operators.CompareFloatingPoint</Add>
    </Fit.Operators>
</suiteConfig>
```

Including in the Fitnesse markup like this
`!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer -c C:\fit\tests\SuiteConfig.xml %p}`

Output of test currently looks like this

```css
.fail, span.fail * {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}
.pass, span.pass * {
    background-color: #c1e2b3;
    color: #081109;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    width: auto;
}
table > thead > tr > th, table > tbody > tr > th, table > tfoot > tr > th, table > thead > tr > td, table > tbody > tr > td, table > tfoot > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
table > thead > tr > th, table > tbody > tr > th, table > tfoot > tr > th, table > thead > tr > td, table > tbody > tr > td, table > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody><tr>
  <td colspan="3"><span class="fit_interpreter">tests.Division</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><span class="fit_member">numerator</span></td>
  <td><span class="fit_member">denominator</span></td>
  <td><span class="fit_member">quotient?</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="pass">5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>12.6</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td class="pass">4.2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td class="pass">25</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td class="fail">3.14 <span class="fit_label">expected</span><hr>3.14285714285714 <span class="fit_label">actual</span></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Looks correct - what problem did you have?

Comment: @MikeStockdale I am trying to get the Division test here http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample working. This test uses the Slim test system, so it provides the ~= operator. I am using Fit, not slim. I was under the iimpression Cell Operators would allow for similar functionality.

Comment: What does your test look like when you run it?

Comment: @MikeStockdale I added output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell operator is loaded correctly, the problem is the cell operator doesn't do what you hoped it does.  The `CompareFloatingPoint` operator doesn't use the precision of the expected value (3.14), it uses the precision of the string representation of the actual value (3.14285714285714). As you commented, fitSharp doesn't support the ~= operator, you could use >= 3.14 and < 3.15 on two rows, but not quite as nice!

Comment: What's it sounds like I need to use a technique like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489771/how-to-test-approximate-values-in-fitnesse for the Fit test system, otherwise use ~= with Slim